# Error in WooCommerce USPS Shipping Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, woocommerce, usps

I am getting following error in WooCommerce USPS Shipping Plugin:"

```
USPS REQUEST FAILEDcURL error 5: Could not resolve proxy: http_proxy
```

Can someone please help with on how to resolve this?

I googled it but could not find anything related.

Answer (score 1):

In [cURL documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) the code 5 means that a proxy server cannot be resolved (it cannot be reached in a DNS query):

> **CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_PROXY (5)**
>
> Couldn't resolve proxy. The given proxy host could not be resolved.

The **WF_Shipping_USPS** class in the plugin source uses **wp_remote_post()** to communicate with the USPS API. I think you have something wrong in configuration for proxy and/or have the "http_proxy" defined as string in some config file or even at the environment vars in Linux.

You can check wp-config.php for the lines (just a sample config, you data may be different):

```
/* Configure proxy Server */
define('WP_PROXY_HOST', 'www-cache.leeds.ac.uk');
define('WP_PROXY_PORT', '3128');
define('WP_PROXY_USERNAME', '');
define('WP_PROXY_PASSWORD', '');
define('WP_PROXY_BYPASS_HOSTS', 'localhost');
```

If your server is linux, you can try:

```
echo $HTTP_PROXY
```

And see if there are something here that is wrong.

To me somewhere you have the string "http_proxy" configured as a proxy host. If you have a proxy correct this by putting the right config. If you do not have a proxy, remove this string and try to disable proxy usage for Wordpress.